# Can you tell how a particular linear transformation is defined looking at its matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is there a way to determine how a linear map $T\in{\cal L}(V,W)$ is defined when looking at its matrix?

V and W denote finite dimensional vector spaces and ${\cal L}(V,W)$ denotes the vector space of linear maps from V to W.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by **its** matrix? Depending on basis chosen there are more than a one matrix associated to the linear map.

Comment: Right. I should have said "some matrix"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the bases on $V$ and $W$ with respect to which the matrix is represented, then yes, you can recover what the original transformation is. Here is the formal statement:

> Let $n,m\geq 1$ be integers, $V,W$ be vector spaces over a field $\Bbb{F}$, of dimension $n$ and $m$ respectively. $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be ordered bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively. Then, there is a linear isomorphism $\Phi_{\beta,\gamma}:\mathcal{L}(V,W) \to M_{m\times n}(\Bbb{F})$

Suppose $\beta = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ and $\gamma = \{w_1, \dots, w_m\}$. Then, the inverse mapping $\Phi_{\beta,\gamma}^{-1}:M_{m\times n}\to \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is given as follows: given a matrix $A = (a_{ij})$, the corresponding linear transformation $T= \Phi_{\beta,\gamma}^{-1}(A):V \to W$ is obtained by mapping the basis $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ as follows
\begin{align}
T(v_j) &= \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij} w_i
\end{align}
Of course, if you know how a linear transformation acts on a basis you know it everywhere, because given any $\xi\in V$, we first write it as $\xi= \sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j v_j$ for some scalars $\xi_j\in \Bbb{F}$. Then,
\begin{align}
T(\xi) &= \sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j T(v_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m \xi_j a_{ij} w_i.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You also need to know the relevant bases of $V$ and $W$. Once you know the bases and the matrix elements then you have all the information about the linear map.